# Runtime Error message: loadView instantiated view controller with identifier ViewController from storyboard Main,but didn't get a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to develop an iOS application with swift having a custom cells in UItableview.

1 - my controller's (personalinformation) codes :

```
import UIKit

struct CellData {
let image: UIImage?
let message: String?
}

class personalinformation: UITableViewController {

var data = [CellData]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    data = [CellData.init(image: UIImage(named: "sampleimage1"), message: "this is first one"), CellData.init(image: UIImage(named: "sampleimage2"), message: "this is second one"), CellData.init(image: UIImage(named: "sampleimage3"), message: "this is third one"), CellData.init(image: UIImage(named: "sampleimage4"), message: "this is last one")]
    self.tableView.register(acustomcell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! acustomcell
    cell.myimage = data[indexPath.row].image
    cell.mymessage = data[indexPath.row].message
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
}
```

2 - custom cell codes are here, basically creates a simple custom cell file (customcell.swift):

```
import UIKit
class acustomcell: UITableViewCell {

var mymessage: String?
var myimage: UIImage?

var messageView: UITextView = {
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
}()

var myimageView: UIImageView = {
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = false
    return imageView
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
{
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addSubview(myimageView)
    self.addSubview(messageView)
    
    myimageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    myimageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myimageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    myimageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myimageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myimageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myimageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myimageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let mymessage = mymessage {
        messageView.text = mymessage
    }
    if let myimage = myimage {
        myimageView.image = myimage
    }
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Everything looks OK but at Run time, I am getting the following error message when I open the view at simulator (no compiler errors):

```
Thread 1: "-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier \"UIViewController-dtk-hv-3QF\" from storyboard \"Main\", but didn't get a UITableView."
```

Comment: The error explains the problem. You are subclassing `UITableViewController` but the root view of the scene is not a `UITableView`  You need to ensure that your table view is assigned to the `view` outlet of the view controller, or if you want the root view to be something else, subclass `UIViewController`

Comment: Please check your main storyboard. Error is saying its not able to get tableview from UITableViewController. Make sure have personalinformation is mapping to UItableViewController in storyboard

Comment: Yes, I hooked the TableviewController (personal information) to tableview in the view layout, looks like, it's a Xcode problem that previous hook is not deleted when I hook it. I deleted the view completely and added a new one and then added all code back to the new Tableviewcontroller with the same name (personalinformation) and hooked it to tableview again. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here is the difference between dragging a usual vc and table template vc ( You should go with option 1 )

[image]